# How can I create query that (counting values inside Column)

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 companies 1001,1002 ,1003 it could be more and 11 containers with different sizes 1,2,3,4, 5 I want return only the containers that are in the companies that have the same amount or more of specified numbers. for example if I want 2 containers from size 1 and 3 containers from size 2 then only the containers in the company that has 2 or more of size 1 and 3 or more of size 2 should appear let's say that only company 1001 has them then it should appear alone.
I tried different queries and post one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878249/msg-156-level-15-state-1-line-22-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-having) but they recommend me to post a new question with the problem that I'm training to make query for.

(Company info and containers info are in two separate tables)

this is what I get when I remove having (basically all the containers in the city that has been selected)

```
CoID    CoName          ContainerID   Price size1 size2  size3 size4 size5
6000001 hbjjvCompany    2000002       50    1     0      0     0     0
6000001 hbjjvCompany    2000003       50    1     0      0     0     0
6000002 NCompany        2000004       50    1     0      0     0     0
6000001 hbjjvCompany    2000005       100   0     1      0     0     0
6000002 NCompany        2000007       100   0     1      0     0     0
6000001 hbjjvCompany    2000008       200   0     0      1     0     0
6000001 hbjjvCompany    2000009       200   0     0      1     0     0
6000001 hbjjvCompany    2000010       200   0     0      1     0     0
6000002 NCompany        2000011       200   0     0      1     0     0
6000001 hbjjvCompany    2000012       400   0     0      0     0     1
6000003 ghhaCo          2000014       200   0     1      0     0     0
```

what should I get is

```
CoID    CoName                  size1 size2  size3 size4 size5
6000001 hbjjvCompany            2     1      3     0     1
```

of course I want the containers id and the price but I put it heare like this to make it clear that my query show all the containers even if i removed the ContainerID and price.

Comment: Hi, as you are quite new here, please allow me some hints in order to help you to get answers "to the point". If you refer to another question (I suppose it's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35878249/5089204), you should include a link. And please: Create a test scenario (either post SQL here or create a [Fiddle](www.sqlfiddle.com). Add test data and the expected output. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's this you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable(CoID INT,CoName VARCHAR(100),ContainerID INT,Price DECIMAL(10,4),size1 INT,size2 INT,size3 INT,size4 INT,size5 INT);
INSERT INTO #YourTable VALUES
 (6000001,'hbjjvCompany',2000002,50,1,0,0,0,0)
,(6000001,'hbjjvCompany',2000003,50,1,0,0,0,0)
,(6000002,'NCompany',2000004,50,1,0,0,0,0)
,(6000001,'hbjjvCompany',2000005,100,0,1,0,0,0)
,(6000002,'NCompany',2000007,100,0,1,0,0,0)
,(6000001,'hbjjvCompany',2000008,200,0,0,1,0,0)
,(6000001,'hbjjvCompany',2000009,200,0,0,1,0,0)
,(6000001,'hbjjvCompany',2000010,200,0,0,1,0,0)
,(6000002,'NCompany',2000011,200,0,0,1,0,0)
,(6000001,'hbjjvCompany',2000012,400,0,0,0,0,1)
,(6000003,'ghhaCo',2000014,200,0,1,0,0,0);

SELECT CoID
      ,CoName
      ,SUM(Price) AS SumPrice
      ,SUM(size1) AS CountSize1
      ,SUM(size2) AS CountSize2
      ,SUM(size3) AS CountSize3
      ,SUM(size4) AS CountSize4
      ,SUM(size5) AS CountSize5
FROM #YourTable
GROUP BY CoID,CoName;

--Clean up
DROP TABLE #YourTable;
```

The result

```
CoID    CoName           SumPrice  s1  s2  s3  s4  s5
6000003 ghhaCo           200.0000   0   1   0   0   0
6000001 hbjjvCompany    1200.0000   2   1   3   0   1
6000002 NCompany         350.0000   1   1   1   0   0
```

Comment: No I'm not trying to get the sum of each column.

Comment: @Nysa Well, the result you posted is exactly this. Your numbers seem to be counts of containers of a given size. The `SUM` of counts is the accumulated count... What else do you need?

Comment: What I want is to count each size in the original containerSize column in the container table then compare them with given number I posted it in my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878249/msg-156-level-15-state-1-line-22-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-having/35878376?noredirect=1#comment59423022_35878376

Comment: @Nysa, In your question you state an expected output for CoID=6000001. This is absolutely the same as my second line... I'm puzzled...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see the complete result in my phone I checked it now in my pc. It's correct but I want return only the company that possess the same amount or more that I specify for each size.

Comment: @Nysa It's the easiest way to pack the whole query as a CTE and use this as if it was a table. You can use `WHERE` or any other extension With this you avoid your troubles with column aliases... Do you know what I'm speaking about?

Comment: I will tell you what I understood and please tell me if it's wrong. what I have to do is to separate them for simplicity then use where for my conditions but why (insert ) can't this be achieved without creating temporary table ?

Comment: @Nysa the CTE is kind of temporary table. But it is inlined (*ad-hoc sql*). Not absolutely the same but close to...

Comment: hmm. Isn't it time consuming? and I want to ask about the insert. my data is from different tables the data that is written in the insert you wrote is from different tables in my database . it's the same right? Sorry if I'm asking a lot. I don't  have that much of experience in the database.